# How to use parameter inside function without passing?

Tags: php, mysql, function

I'm trying to use db connection parameter inside function, i tried to global it but it does not working.

```
$host = 'localhost';
    $username = 'b**s';
    $password = '1******m';
    $dbname = 'b*********e';        
    $connection = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($connection->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
```

When i'm executing the query it returning error, becuase i didn't pass `$connection` parameter inside function.

```
function insertData(){
        {......}
        if($connection->query($sql)){           
            $response['success'] = 'User record successfully added!'; 
        }
    }
```

Can anyone guide me what is best to use without passing parameter inside function. I would like to appreciate if someone guide me.

Comment: You want to pass the $connection as function parameter? If the connection initializer and this function are in the same class, make $connection as private member of the class and use it in all the functions. No need to pass parameter wherever you call it

Comment: @RehbanKhatri I'm not using class, there is no class inside my code

Comment: Then you must have a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function you should do something like

```
global $connection;
```

then use it below like

```
if($connection->query($sql)){           
      $response['success'] = 'User record successfully added!'; 
 }
```

This is well documented in manual, i suggest you go have a look.

Comment: Database connections must be used ONLY when required. global just makes it available everywhere and causes no transparency between your database and database driver in PHP. So a singleton class is always preferred for connecting database where you get connection when required and query the database.

Comment: It will work @Mr.Developer but I'm just sayin, this is not the right way.

Comment: @Mr.Developer i assume you have a prior knowledge of scopes. The reason we are declaring it global beforehand is telling the function that this is not a local variable. The one in question you have is local, which is not defined and therefore wont work.

Answer (score 1):

Create a database class and access it by object

```
<?php

class Database {

    private static $db;
    private $connection;

    private function __construct() {
        $this->connection = new MySQLi(/* credentials */);
    }

    function __destruct() {
        $this->connection->close();
    }

    public static function getConnection() {
        if (self::$db == null) {
            self::$db = new Database();
        }
        return self::$db->connection;
    }
}

?>
```

Then just use `$db = Database::getConnection();` wherever I need it.

Comment: I'm not using class, there is no class inside my code